# Remove or hide specific string in a url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, codeigniter-4

I have this url `https://test.app/myapp/login`. All I want is to remove the 'myapp' string using .htaccess. This is what I tried so far.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]     

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?myapp=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```

But its not working. Btw using codeigniter 4

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, so you mean  you are hitting URL `https://test.app/myapp/login` and you want it be redirected it `https://test.app/` in browser?

Comment: I want it to be `https://test.app/login`, just like when your removing the index.php

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteRule ^myapp/login/?$  /login [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```